# How can I connect and implement websockets with Django?

Tags: python, django, websocket

I would like to use websockets for my projects , but i have no idea what do i need to do. I use django for back end. how I can combine them.? this is the only question i have. thanks guys.)

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't support WebSockets on it own.

If you want to get into WebSocket architecture using Django you should see [django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels)